Latex table content overflow
I have a table with multiple long texts, and can't fit them into page width. I have figured out an optimal set of column widths(with trial-and-error according to textwidth), but when I put the contents, it either breaks the table, or doesn't work.
Later on, I made a workaround, it's not merged row anymore, looks horrible, and since I'll be using the table in a paper, I can't use that. My workaround:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newgeometry{
    textheight=9in,
    textwidth=6.5in,
    top=1in,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[h]{p{1.2cm}p{3.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{2cm}p{1.8cm}p{3.5cm}}
\caption{Sample table}
\label{table:sample} \\
\hline
\textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Slightly loooooooong name} & \textbf{Col 4} & \textbf{Col 5} & \textbf{Col 6} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Slightly looooong name} & \textbf{Col 4} & \textbf{Col 5} & \textbf{Col 6} \\ \hline
\endhead

\\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\\ \hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{2}{*}{lorem ipsum} & voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 111,111 & 222,222 & 333,333 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad \\
& voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 444,444 & 555,555 & 666,666  \\ 

\end{longtable}


\end{document}

For example, in the attached image you can see that although I specified column width, it's overflowing. What I need is, all the data between Col 1 and Col 6 should be adjusted to these 2 columns' heights, preferably with my specified column widths.

When I used \makecell, it looked like a combination of 3 rows. I have tried other ways (multirows with width, etc.) but couldn't solve my issue.
What I essentially want is something like the following image:


Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

In particular, please do tell us which document class you employ, what the main document font size, and how wide the margins are. Alternatively, how wide is the text block supposed to be.

Aside: How is LaTeX supposed to hyphenate the "words" loooooooong and looooong?

Please also clarify what you mean by "I have figured out an optimal set of column widths". What makes the widths "optimal"?

Apologies about earlier mistakes. I have updated the code snippet into MWE, provided document class, textwidth, margin, font. @JoséCarlosSantos

About hyphenation: I'm not sure about it, but I think it should do it according to the column width, if it's possible to do so. @Mico

But that depends on the words used.  LaTeX knows how to hyphenate in general.  It doesn't know how to hyphenate looooooong.  Is there an actual word you're having trouble hyphenating?

If I understood well, you need this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newgeometry{
    textheight=9in,
    textwidth=6.5in,
    top=1in,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={Sample table},
  label={table:sample},
  ]{
  colspec={Q[l,1.2cm]Q[l,3.8cm]Q[l,1.8cm]Q[l,2cm]Q[l,1.8cm]Q[l,3.5cm]},
  hline{1,2,Z}={solid},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  rowhead=1,
  }
Col 1 & Col 2 & Slightly loooooooong name & Col 4 & Col 5 & Col 6 \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l} lorem ipsum & voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 111,111 & 222,222 & 333,333 & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad \\
& voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 444,444 & 555,555 & 666,666  \\ 
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
Other & lines & just & to & show & the page break\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}



Yes, this works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!

Something like this?

Note that I've dropped the \multirow directive, as it makes no useful contribution here.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newgeometry{%
    textheight=9in, textwidth=6.5in,
    top=1in, headheight=14pt, headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\hyphenation{looooooo-ong loooo-ong} % choose something sensible

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} P{1.2cm} P{3.9cm} *{3}{P{1.8cm}} P{3.9cm} @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption{Sample table} \label{table:sample} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & 
\textbf{Slightly loooooooong name} & 
\textbf{Col 4} & \textbf{Col 5} & 
\textbf{Col 6} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued from preceding page} \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & 
\textbf{Slightly looooong name} & 
\textbf{Col 4} & \textbf{Col 5} & 
\textbf{Col 6} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of longtable

lorem ipsum & 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 
111,111 & 222,222 & 333,333 & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad \\ 
\addlinespace
& 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium & 
444,444 & 555,555 & 666,666 \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Thanks for the table header aligning. But I was wondering if it's possible to have the 2nd row (voluptatem..., 444..., 555..., 666...) to be merged with first row for columns "Col 2" to "Col 5". "Col 1" and "Col 6" should be spanned across these merged rows. That was what I had been struggling with.

@KawshikBanerjee - Please clarify what you mean by "merged row". E.g., should "444,444" be directly below "111,111" in column 3, or should there be a one-cell gap in order to make "444,444" also line up with the second instance of "voluptatem ... laudantiem"?

There should not be any line gap, and "444,444" should be lined with the second instance of "volup ..." I have edited my original post and attached the final output I am expecting to make. Apologies for not making it clear at the beginning.
